# send message to running python process

Tags: python, linux

I want to start pythonScriptA with crontab, keeping it running for several hours each day.

Then I want to launch -independently from pythonScriptA- pythonScriptB. How is it possible to give -from within pythonScriptB- inputs, commands etc. to pythonScriptA?

The challenge is, that both scripts must be launched independently (please don't ask why, it's just like this).

A possible solution might be (I don't know if that's technically possible):
- When pythonScriptB is launched, it looks out for running pythonScriptA's by searching python scripts with the specific .py-filename
- pythonScriptB then gives pythonScriptA specific inputs or commands.

Comment: Why is it executed once a day if it should be runnig all the time. Wouldn a service be suited better?

Comment: some precisions:
pythonScriptA is executed once a day by crontab. it then runs 12 hours and terminates itself (except when pythonScriptB tells it to terminate earlier, and that's exactly the thing I don't know how to do).

pythonScriptB runs non-stop since it awaits at all time UDP-packages from the network. when it gets certain UDP-packages, it should be able to control pythonScriptA, especially to tell pythonScriptA to terminate or to tell it to do other things.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution: Unix Domain Sockets. They make it possible to communicate between two processes that have been launched independently. Am I right?